# How can I get FireFox to automatically fill in an entire form?

Tags: firefox, forms, automation

Firefox remembers individual fields but I can't seem to just fill in the form with a single click (this is a form I have filled in a number of times before).  A long time ago there was a FireFox plugin that did this, but it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [Autofill forms](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-forms/) add-on.

Answer (score 1):

There are many password manager add-ons that can assist with this. I personally use [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/). You could also try [Roboform](http://www.roboform.com/). Both of these work great! Their form filling capabilities work quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some addons I've tried - I wound up using **FireForm** as it seemed to work well - just click on a toolbar button to fill in a form. **Autofill Forms** was similar but it seems to have some problems with the UI.

(I didn't have enough reputation for more than 2 of the links)

### FireForm

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireform
8,018 users
latest 2014-01

Includes support for multiple profiles and custom field names.
data is not encrypted

### Autofill Forms

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-forms
75,736 users
latest 2012

adds a toolbar button (pencil icon)
dialog is sometimes too big to see - but can right click on a form field and click "add rule for this field" to bring up window correctly

### Autofill

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autofill-262804/
15,582 users
latest 2013-02

source at github.com/thdoan/autofill-firefox

### FillForms

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fillforms/
2,598 users
latest 2011

fill out all forms with alt+q
but there's no entry form, it's per website, not general, and values are encrypted
saves encrypted info to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\.default\fillform\data.txt

### SimpleFill

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/simplefill/
1,600 users
latest 2014-04

You need two mouse-clicks per field to fill up any form.

### FormBug

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/formbug/
1,223 users
latest 2013-09

helps with developing sites